# Reporting Services and checkboxes to specify WHERE Clause

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report embedded in an ASP.NET page.  The ASP.NET page has some checkboxes that the user can select which datapoints they want to have show up in the report.

In the code behind file I am setting up part of the WHERE clause to be used in the query based on which checkboxes are checked.

I am putting this string into a report parameter and am not sure how to implement that parameter in the query.  Simply placing the parameter in the query thinking the value of the string would come across does not work.  I have the correct syntax in the string that is being passed into the report.

How do I properly use a Report Parameter to alter the WHERE Clause of the query?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base the report on a stored procedure that takes a BIT parameter for each of the checkbox values.

Build the dynamic SQL in the stored procedure and execute it.